# Kubera references for worship

Tags: worship, puja, kubera

Where are references of *sUtras*, *dhyAna* or *mantras* (or related) for worshiping Kubera in the right way to incorporate him in the daily *pUja*?

Comment: https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_deities_misc/kuberAShTottaranAmAvalI.html

Comment: [Skanda Purana 7.1.293](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc627081.html) = _A devotee should worship the deity Kubera on fifth lunar day with sweet scents, flowers and unguents. He will, without any obstacle, obtain unparalleled wealth of hidden treasuries._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the *Kubera Mantra*.

> **धनाध्यक्षो यक्षपतिर्लोकपालो धनेश्वरः । सगुह्यकस्सयक्षश्च प्रतिगृह्णातु मे बलिम् ॥**

> **dhanādhyakṣo yakṣapatirlokapālo dhaneśvaraḥ |
> saguhyakassayakṣaśca pratigṛhṇātu me balim ||**

> **[ Natyshastra 3:64-66 ]**

> O the superintendent of [all] wealth, the king of Yakṣas, the guardian of the world, the lord of riches, ye along with Guhyakas and Yakṣas accept this my best offering.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is it possible to have a transliteration to understand better ?

Comment: @LuckyPashu I added it. Pls accept my answer if u r satisfied 